# Internal Intent to pass data to other app

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, bundle

I am using an Intent to Open a VideoPlayer App in user's phone. 
I am storing some videos in cache directory of user when activity is created.
The name of my videos has to be in specific format, that's why I can't change them on time of its creation,but when the video opens through an intent, i want to change the title which the user sees when the video is played.

So the code is as follows

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, pathUri);
  intent.setDataAndType(pathUri, "video/mp4");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The intent may open an app like photos, mxplayer etc which is capable of playing the video.

Other than passing the uri, i also want to pass a title through my intent.
Is it possible to change title of the video when is it played through mxplayer,photos etc. I just want to temporarily change name of file when played in third party app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add this line to intent `intent.putExtra("title","your video name");`

Comment: @HemantParmar I guess you didn't understood my question. I know how to pass data through intent. How i am gonna extract that data when the video plays in photos or mxplayer

Comment: String videoInfo = Intent.getExtras("nameAssignedToValueInPutExtra");

Comment: @petyr Please read my question again. I know how to extract data from intent